# Auto-apply migrations/metadata version breaks the app for version 3

Tags: hasura, hasura-docker, hasura-cli

I using hasura and trying to auto-apply migrations/metadata , so when a new PR is open it will set a new postgresql db for the app and then the migration should run before start the server

here is the code I'm trying for the Dockerfile

```
FROM hasura/graphql-engine:v2.33.2.cli-migrations-v3

COPY hasura/metadata /hasura-metadata
COPY hasura/migrations /hasura-migrations

CMD graphql-engine \
  --metadata-database-url $HASURA_GRAPHQL_METADATA_DATABASE_URL \
    serve
```

But when i start function not migration. If i remove **COPY hasura/metadata /hasura-metadata** migrations migrate function into database success. I don't know why.
When i research it same issue
https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/5172
but when i add
HASURA_GRAPHQL_CLI_ENVIRONMENT=default
It not resolve for me. Please help?